# How can I format a float in Python delimited by width, not by precision?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, number-formatting

I am looking for a way to format a number string in Python in such a way that I have a fixed width, regardless the precision. I'll give an example below:

Suppose I want to format the float for a fixed width = 8 and precision = 4. If I use the following code:

```
number = 3.141516
'{:8.4f}'.format(numero)
```

it works well for small numbers. But if I want to format a number like 1000000, the output is `1000000.0000`, thus giving a width greater than 8.

Is there a way I could set the formatter in a such a way I can get a fixed width in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using `{:8g}` might do what you want.

Comment: @TomKarzes it really did, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of the number also depends on the precision. As you want a fixed width, I would suggest you to use f strings and set the precision to be equal to the width in case the precision value is more than the width.

**Syntax for f strings**: f'{value:{width}.{precision}}'

- The precision includes integer + decimal value

This is how you could use it:

```
    n = 3.141516
    print(f'{n:{8}.{4}}')
```

The output that you will get is:

> ```
>    3.142
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totaly sure of what you are asking. should the width of 8 include the dot?

see if this answer your question:

```
print(f'{str(float(number)) + "0"*8}'[:8])
```

but note that in a 7 digit integer a dot will be left by the end so you need to catch this exception. I guess by adding a 0 on front of the number and replacing the dot so it maintains the 8 width, but it depend on what you are searching.

Comment: Yes, the width should include the dot, I'm aiming to write numbers in a fixed format file. Thanks for the tip